# linux iptables redirect outgoing traffic to local port

Tags: linux, iptables

I want redirect all outgoing traffic with port `8080` to local port `8080`

for example i create server with this command `nc -l -p 8080` and i want when use this command `nc 1.2.3.4 8080` , `nc` redirect and connect to `127.0.0.1:8080`

i try with this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP
```

but not worked!

how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local originated traffic isn't passing through nat/POSTROUTING chain. You should add rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Additional info:

1. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg
2. http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/index.html Chapter 4.